# How to animate width on parent element with display:block/none on child elem

Tags: html, css

I have two children in one parent element where first child is always visible but second one is visible on hover only. Since I have fit-content set for parent's width when I hover the parent elem expands. What I need is a smooth transition for this expansion. I do all this in React. Thanks

Check context please:

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: #f31d84;
  width: fit-content;
}
.icon{
  margin: 5px;
}
.text{
  display: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

.parent:hover .text{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='icon'>
      icon
    </div>
    <div class='text'>
      texttexttexttext
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution for my problem. The code:

```
<div>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='icon'>
      icon
    </div>
    <div className='text-wrapper'>
      <div class='text'>
        texttexttexttext
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

.parent{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: #f31d84;
  width: fit-content;
}
.icon{
  margin: 5px;
}
.text{
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 0;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: 5s ease;
}
.text-wrapper{
  width: auto;
}

.parent:hover .text{
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate what is not a value. I mean that going from `display: none` to `display: block` can't be animate because they are not values.

Comment: Well, I know that however I don't actually need to animate display block or display none. I can do that using max-width or max-height with opacity or visibility. What I need here is  to animate width's expansion on parents div which is expanding due to the second child appearing

Answer (score 0):

It's a wrong implementation. Your parent element width in this example doesn't change on hover. If u want to animate things, a good practice is set width 0 to the child element and when parent element gets hovered div with the class `text` gets 50% of parent's width. you can achieve this through css only and react way. If u are interested let me know to edit this answer.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. Have you tried it on jsfiddle? It represents my problem and it does increase width for parent element.
And yes, could you please elaborate on your way of doing it?

Comment: Could you share a full answer rather than asking the OP to contact you if he wants to get it?

Comment: @PCPbiscuit yes i've checked the jsfiddle. The parent's width doesn't change at all. You just add another child which pushes the other child.

Comment: @Puka my answer would  be considered irrelevant if i don't understand what he/she wants. So im asking for more info

Comment: @PCPbiscuit  And also Puka answer is kinda what I was going to share with u but in react way with inline styles. The base idea is the same

Answer (score 0):

Transitioning from `display: none` to `display: block` will not work. Indeed, there is only a finite number of CSS properties that can be animated and `display` is not one (see: [Animatable CSS properties on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)).

The common way to do such a thing is to transition from `width: 0` to `width: 50%` (or whatever value you want your block to be, just remember that `auto` will not work).

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: #f31d84;
  width: fit-content;
}

.icon {
  margin: 5px;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.parent:hover .text {
  width: 50%;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='icon'>
      icon
    </div>
    <div class='text'>
      texttexttexttext
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well... I tried doing something like that but you can see it closes very weirdly and I need a smooth animation